# Using AWK, how remove a section that contains a particular pattern

Tags: awk, gawk

I’m new on AWK but I need to start with a rule that appears to be not very simple, at least for me. Maybe someone can help me to find the solution.

I need to search and remove some lines that contain a particular pattern. As for the bekow example: I need remove the entire section (three lines) that contain the name "pippo2"

Input file:

```
   <Name>
      Pippo1
   </Name>
   <Name>
      Pippo2
   </Name>
   <Name>
      Pippo3
   </Name>
```

Desired output file:

```
   <Name>
      Pippo1
   </Name>
   <Name>
      Pippo3
   </Name>
```

All the best
Mauro

---

**Hello!**
Thanks all for your suggestions.

But I am sorry to confirm your comments, in fact using a structure a bit more complex the suggested filters stop working :-(

Here is the more complex structure:

```
  <Name>
     <data>Pippo1</data>
  </Name>
  <Name>
     <data>Pippo2</data>
  </Name>
  <LastName>
     <data>Pippo3</data>
  </LastName>
```

Comment: It is not robust to use awk for xml in general. You can in this simple case, but the approach will bite you eventually.

Comment: To be true, it will bite you surely.

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` to the rescue!

you need a regex aware `RS` for the following (gawk supports)

```
 awk -v RS="</[^>]+>" '!/Pippo2/{printf "%s", $0 RT}' pippos

   <Name>
      Pippo1
   </Name>
   <Name>
      Pippo3
   </Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If file `t.dat` contains your data the following `awk` script will do the job:

```
$ awk '/<Name>/{notFound=1} {str=str $0} /Pippo2/{notFound=0} /<\/Name>/{if(notFound){print str;} str=""; notFound=1;}' t.dat
<Name>Pippo1</Name>
<Name>Pippo3</Name>
```

Of course this solution is not very generic - it works only on the data files with the schema like yours - each record (possibly multiline) is enclosed with `<Name> ... </Name>` tags.

Comment: BTW, I agree with the comments under your original question - you should not use AWK for that ... :)